# Contain Laravel 8 rightJoin data in its own property

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm successfully doing a rightJoin in Laravel 8 Eloquent. I'd like to isolate data from the table I am joining as its own property on the object.

My Eloquent code:

```
return Book
    ::rightJoin('tableB', 'tableB.book_id', '=', 'book.id')
    ->where('tableA.user_id', $uid)
    ->get();
```

Right now the data I am getting is formatted as e.g.:

```
[
    tableA.col1,
    tableA.col2,
    tableB.col1,
    tableB.col2
]
```

I'd like to have the returned objected structured like this instead:

```
[
    tableA.col1,
    tableA.col2,
    tableB [
        col1,
        col2
    ]
]
```

I'm doing this to get a list of books that the user has started, and want the progress info as its own property to satisfy the structure expected on the front end.

I could of course process and restructure the data using PHP on the back end, but this feels rather ugly. Is there a Laravel 8 Eloquent feature that can help me structure the returned data in the way the front end right now expects?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [`belongsTo`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) (or `hasOne` depending on the case) relationship.

### Models/Book.php

```
public function tableB() {
  return $this->belongsTo(TableB::class);
}
```

Then when on the eloquent builder you can use `with` to retrieve the `books` and the `TableB` records associated with each `book`

```
$books = Book::whereHas('tableB', function($query) {
  $query->where('id', ...); // this is a query that will put a constraint of which results are returned. Adjust according to your necessity
})->get();
```

Comment: Hello null, and thanks for your answer. I've not been able to fully implement the solution you propose, but I've made progress. And so I am wondering: it looks like the solution you suggest will return ALL the books, whereas I want to return only those that the user has access to with the query I've posted.  The card design for books in All Books and My Books sections on the front end is is being reused in the form of a component, and hence I'm trying to return API data in the same format for both sections.

Comment: I've discovered whereHas, and am trying to utilse it to solve my problem...